# soql select individual CaseComment with all its FeedComments

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to select all comments ,feeds and feedcomments for an individual case.
The hierarchy is like

```
Case
    |
     CaseComment
                |
                 FeedComments(commnets or feeds under a CaseComment)
```

I could not find any relation between `CaseComments` and `FeedComments` nor `CaseComments` and `CaseFeeds`.
How can I select all together in a `soql` or individual `soqls` which relates `Case, CaseComment,CaseFeed,FeedComment`?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

The query you've included in the comment looks good. I'd write it as something like that:

```
SELECT Id, Body, ParentId, Parent.CaseNumber, CreatedDate,
    (SELECT Id, CommentBody, CommentType FROM FeedComments)
FROM CaseFeed
ORDER BY Parent.CaseNumber, CreatedDate
```

[image]

(this is sample output rendered in [Real Force Explorer](https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/wiki/Home), a pretty neat tool)

If I'll click into the "2 records" bit I can drill down to the fields selected from FeedComment for "this" CaseFeed:

[image]

If your query renders differently for you (some stuff is blank) - maybe try this different editor or even go to https://workbench.developerforce.com

If only some comments contain text - they might be uploaded images for example - filter them by `CommentType = 'TextComment'`?

---

**ORIGINAL**

> FeedComments(commnets or feeds under a CaseComment)

No, not really. [FeedComment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm) is a Chatter table that can link to many objects but CaseComment is not one of them.

[image]

Maybe study the [Chatter Entity Relationship Diagram](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm)?

Anyway - relationship to feed* objects doesn't have a nice name exposed so we can't query it all in one go:

[image]

I think you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber,
    (SELECT Id, CommentBody FROM CaseComments),
    (SELECT Id, Body FROM Feeds)
FROM Case

SELECT Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, CommentBody
FROM FeedComment
WHERE ParentId = :caseIdHere
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am sorry I can't vote up your answer because of my reputation :(

Comment: Don't worry, you'll reach the 15 points soon :D If you think the question is answered you can always tick the "check" icon to accept an answer. I'm not putting pressure on you, do it when / if you feel comfortable. Maybe you'll have follow-up questions, maybe somebody will post a better answer...

Comment: sure. And yes you are right, I have a follow-up question.Is there any way to select a Case and CaseCommnet with all feeds under an individual CaseComment?
I am using query:

"Select c.Id, c.Body, (Select Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, CommentBody, IsDeleted, InsertedById, CommentType, RelatedRecordId From FeedComments) From CaseFeed c where c.ParentId='some case id'"

which returns
1)CaseFeeds with its body and FeedComments grouped by individual CaseFeed.

2)FeedComments with empty body grouped by individual CaseCommnet-how to relate this to a CaseComment?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. As far as I know, Case Comments (related list of text fields under a case) can't have feeds, comments on themselves etc. Maybe you can post a screenshot of (anonymized) data you try to fetch in one go? Or write out a text table how you'd imagine the result to look like...

Comment: I do have a snapshot but can't upload it because of my reputation.
Would you mind looking at this url to snapshot?    
http://oi39.tinypic.com/20jh4p1.jpg      

As per the snapshot,  
How do I select comment2 which is a CaseComment with comment comment 2.1,comment comment 2.2(I don't know what to call them but I found them in FeedComments). 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again.
I can select CaseFeed with FeedComments. The problem is I can't do same with CaseComment. Now when you add a CaseComment it shows it in Feeds section in salesforce UI   http://oi43.tinypic.com/10nayyf.jpg

http://oi42.tinypic.com/292r8f4.jpg

and you can comment under CaseComment in Feed section on UI. I can't select CaseComment(this is a CaseComment 1) with all commnents under it(CaseComment comment 1.1).

Comment: Sorry Frank, I give up. You might try at salesforce.stackexchange.com? I can't reproduce how you managed to get "Dev Dev commented: this is a CaseComment 1.1". Standard Chatter settings don't allow feeds on CaseComment object - there are some workarounds for this like https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtfQAAQ. Simply put - I have no idea from where this content appears in that feed. Do you have some interesting workflows or triggers there? I've even tried force inserting similar to `insert new FeedItem(ParentId = '00a7000000QVoTV', Body = 'test');` - it just doesn't let me;)